# Appendix Numbering

Tags: numbering

I am using this piece of code so that my chapters appear as Chapter One instead of Chapter 1

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\thechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\chaptermark}{\thechapter}{\NUMBERstring{chapter}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

It is working very well for the numbered chapters. The problem is, even my appendix is titled as Appendix One. Is there a way I can leave the numbered chapters as Chapter One, Chapter Two etc, but have the appendix numbered as Appendix A, Appendix B etc?

Comment: It's better if you include a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that people can see what packages etc you need to get your code to work (but don't add code that is not needed). This makes it much easier for people to help you. I've also edited your question to make it easier to read by highlight your code (indent 4 spaces or select and hits the `{}` button).

Answer (score 1):

I think that perhaps you are working too hard as you only need to change the way that the `chapter` counter is printed and for this you only need to redefine `\thechapter`. When you then issue `\appendix` this redefines `\thechapter` to use `\Alph` so all is well:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Numberstring{chapter}}

\let\clearpage\relax% a sleight of hand to put the chapters on 1 page for the image above

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{First chapter}
  \chapter{Second chapter}

  \appendix
  \chapter{First appendix}
  \chapter{Second appendix}
\end{document}
```

This said, you will need to adjust the table of contents.

Answer (score 1):

Use an indirect method for changing the representation of the chapter number in the headings and headers; thus you can change the meaning of the commands when `\appendix` is issued.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fmtcount,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\headingthechapter}{}{}
\newcommand{\headingthechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}}
\patchcmd{\chaptermark}{\thechapter}{\headerthechapter}{}{}
\newcommand{\headerthechapter}{\NUMBERstring{chapter}}
\appto{\appendix}{%
  \renewcommand{\headingthechapter}{\thechapter}%
  \renewcommand{\headerthechapter}{\thechapter}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}

\appendix
\chapter{First appendix}

\end{document}
```

For producing the picture I used A6 paper. The header for the first appendix will be correct (just check it).

[image]